# IAR does not correctly compile C++ file with Auto (extension-based) option enabled

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, iar

This may be a bit of a long shot...

I have a C project and want to include a C++ file however I am getting an error with the following code:

```
//GPIO_CPP.cpp

class GPIO
{
    public:
        uint32_t Port;
        uint32_t Pin;
};

#ifndef __cplusplus
    #error  Enable CPP compilation
#endif
```

This inluded in my main.c as follows:

```
//main.c

#include "GPIO_CPP.cpp"
```

Error:

```
Error[Pe020]: identifier "class" is undefined
```

I have also tried putting this in a header file with .h and .hpp extensions with the same behaviour.

I've placed a compiler check:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
    #error  Enable CPP compilation
#endif
```

which is firing.

My compiler options:

[image: Image of compiler setting]

Comment: Your C project is probably compiling the file as C.  `class` is a C++ keyword.

Comment: Hello Eljay. Yes i suspect this too. However with the IAR compiler option 'Auto (extension-based)' it should pick up this file as C++ as it has a .cpp extension.

Comment: With this limited information I am not able to reproduce the problem. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by *"want to include a C++ file"*? Are you literally trying to `#include "GPIO_CPP.cpp"` into your C file? As others have stated, please create [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the question. I am including the.cpp directly in main.c.

Comment: According to the extension main.c is compiled as c-code. This implies that the content of all included files also are compiled as c-code since `#include "GPIO_CPP.cpp"` works as if the text contained in GPIO_CPP.cpp was written in main.c

Comment: @Johan I see. I am guessing that there is no equivalent of extern "C" for including cpp files from a c project. Meaning the only way to do this is transition to a main.cpp project and extern "C" all C files?

Comment: One thing that stands out here is that you `#include` source files (`.c` and `.cpp`), and not header files. That should not be done, especially if you are mixing C and C++ code. `extern "C"` only tells C++ compiler to C naming scheme for linkage, but doesn't protect you subtle differences when you try to compile seemingly compatible C code with C++ compiler.

Comment: @user694733 I am aware of this, I wanted to rule out the possibility of the compiler not recognising the source file as C++. It is not clear to me how the compiler handles header files when in auto mode. The totally of the documentation on this option in the manual is: _Automatic If you select Automatic, language support is decided automatically depending on the filename extension of the file being compiled:●Files with the filename extension c will be compiled as C source files●Files with the filename extension cpp will be compiled as Extended Embedded C++ source files._

Comment: *"It is not clear to me how the compiler handles header files when in auto mode."* It doesn't. Extension of included file can be anything. `#include` simply copies contents from header to parent file, and results are parsed as part of parent file, using the language rules of compiler you are compiling the parent file with.

Comment: Just to clarify, my comment above applies regardless of the Language setting, and also for all compilers other than IAR too.

Comment: The `#include` preprocessor directive just includes the file verbatim (and then does preprocessor macro expansion).  You could have a Pascal source `#include "foo.pas"` or Fortran `#include "bar.f"`, but the entirety of the `main.c` translation unit will be compiled as C.  The C compiler does not understand C++ any better than it understands Pascal or Fortran.

Comment: Ok I understand what you are meaning. However the utility of the Automatic setting is still opaque to me when using a C project. What's confusing me is this source: https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/compiler/mixing-c-and-c/ _... Alternatively, you want to call C++ functions from your C project. ... Use C-linkage. Put extern "C" { // your function declarations } in header files.
Note that this is required for both C++ and C header files:

    For a C function to be able to call a C++ function._

Comment: _extern "C"_ is not available to the C Compiler. So if you include a C++ file in a C translation unit it wont work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to include C++ module in C project, best way to do this is this:

**gpio.h**

```
#ifndef GPIO_H
#define GPIO_H

// Types accessible to C and C++ modules

struct GPIO
{
    uint32_t Port;
    uint32_t Pin;
};

// Functions accessible to C and C++ modules.
// Use extern "C" only when included to C++ file.
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void foo(uint32_t x);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// Functions accessible to C++ modules only.
// These functions not visible if included to C file.
#ifdef __cplusplus
void bar(uint32_t x);
#endif

#endif
```

**gpio.cpp**

```
#include "gpio.h"

// extern "C" declaration must be visible to this definition to compile with C compatible signature
void foo(uint32_t x) {
    // It's OK to call C++ functions from C compatible functions, 
    // because this is C++ compilation unit.
    bar(x);
}

// This function can be called only from C++ modules
void bar(uint32_t x) {
    // It's OK to call C compatible functions from C++ functions
    foo(x);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "gpio.h"

// Use only C compatible types (struct GPIO) and functions (foo) here
int main(void) {
    foo(1); // ok, because of extern "C"
    bar(1); // invalid because this is C file
}
```

Add `main.c` and `gpio.cpp` to your project tree, and make sure Language setting is set to `Auto`.